# Lone reference error when calling INDEX with RANDBETWEEN in Excel

Tags: excel, montecarlo

I'm trying to do some bootstrapping with a data set in Excel with the formula `=INDEX($H$2:$H$5057,RANDBETWEEN(2,5057))`, where my original data set in is column H. It seems to work most of the time, but there is always approximately one cell that outputs a reference error. Does anyone know why this happens, or how to avoid including that one cell? I'm trying to generate a histogram from this data, and `FREQUENCY` does not play nice with an array with an error in it.

Answer (score 1):

[Please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality/256543#256543):

```
=INDEX($H$2:$H$5057,RANDBETWEEN(1,5056))
```

`=RANDBETWEEN(2,5057)` returns a reasonably arbitrary value of `2` or any integer up to and including `5057`. Used as above this specifies the position in the chosen array (H2:H5057) - that only has 5056 elements, so one problem would be when RANDBETWEEN hits on `5057`. Much easier to observe with just H2:H4 and RANDBETWEEN(2,4).